# Android Worker Threads and the Application life cycle

Tags: android, multithreading, cycle

I have a application in which I have a UART (Serial Comms) to service and several other "tasks" that require separate worker threads to keep the UI responsive.  My problem is in understanding when/where I should create these threads and when they get terminated.  Currently, I am creating them in the OnCreate() of the main UI Activity.  But, this is causing havok, as I recently needed to "jump" from one Activity back to the Main activity.  The recommendation was to use an Intent and StartActivity() with the appropriate flags to "clear to top".  But, this of course causes a whole new set of instances for my threads, and everything unravels.  Should I be using a Service, tied to my UI somehow?  I have subclassed my Main Application, so I have the OnCreate() of my Application.  I'm leaning towards that, but can't seem to grasp the life cycle of the Application versus the Activities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a service. You have an ongoing task that isn't inherently attached to one particular activity.

You can start a long running task with [`startService`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContextWrapper.html#startService%28android.content.Intent%29) and the service will not be killed until it's finished. Meanwhile, `Context#bindService` will keep the service alive as long as anything is bound to it.

Answer (score 2):

General rule of android concurrent programming

- If you need to do something off the UI thread and return a result, use an AsyncTask created when you want to use it
- If you have a 1 off requirement to do some work (say post a webservice request), use an AsyncTask
- If you repeatedly want to do something inside a single activity but you don't need to run after the activity is destroyed or send data to another service, use a thread
- If you need to talk to multiple activities, use a service.
- If you need to run before/after your launching activity ends, use a service